# Pytesseract image to string error messages in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-tesseract

In my Colab installed and imported pytesseract as:

```
!pip install pytesseract
import pytesseract
import cv2
```

Load the image:

```
image = cv2.imread('drive/MyDrive/test.png')
```

Then I'll get this message: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file')
if I write code as:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
```

And this message: /usr/bin/tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
if I write:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (r'/usr/bin/tesseract')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
```

Do you know why and how can I fix it? Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: How did you install Tesseract? There's more than just the Python module to install. See here for an example: https://colab.research.google.com/github/mepky/image_processing-opencv-/blob/master/Assignment.ipynb#scrollTo=ZLNeMRbr_HG4

Comment: Oh thank you, by adding " !sudo apt install tesseract-ocr " at the beginning, I can use Tesseract. I installed it incorrectly, didn't I? How can I upvote your answer?

Comment: Ok, glad it's working. I've added an answer -- instead of just a comment -- so you can accept/upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just be sure you've installed the underlying library the Python module is taking advantage of, for example:

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr

# then you can do: 
!pip install pytesseract
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I pressed the button but it said: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded". I'll try again when I've got enough "reputation". I'm pretty a new member here.

Comment: Oh, got it. You should be able to accept the answer with the checkmark below the voting arrows. That would indicate to other users of the site that your question was answered satisfactorily. Happy coding!

Comment: Happy coding ^^